# Serial device not detected by Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, lubuntu, linux-terminal

“Serial Wacom Tablet stylus” and “Serial Wacom Tablet eraser” [should appear in the xinput list](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217121) in a [Motion LE 1700](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1372076/motion-le1700-tablet-pc.html) Tablet PC, however they are missing in Lubuntu 14 (32bit).

Is there a way to make Lubuntu discover these devices?

Note: Linux Mint and Elementary OS recognize these devices right out the box.

Comment: This is closely related to your other question.  To avoid having it flagged as a duplicate, mention the relationship in the question and add a sentence about what is different in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by recreating an older Ubuntu file “69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules” in “/lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules/” thanks to [Phi at AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/558051/371709)

The stylus pen and eraser are detected in the xinput list and both have pressure sensitivity.

The code is posted [in this response](https://askubuntu.com/a/558051/371709) and is also found in older Ubuntu/Lubuntu versions.